# Dapper QueryMultiple() method returns null from postgreSQL

Tags: c#, dapper

So I'm trying to execute `pl/pgSQL` functions from a web app using `Dapper micro-ORM`. I'm always getting null values irrespective of the values I'm passing as parameters in `QueryMultiple` method; although in database the function gives proper result.

**DAL Method:**

```
public List<JSONData> ExecutePostgres(string spName, List<QueryParam> Params)
    {
        List<JSONData> students = new List<JSONData>();

        using (var dbInstance = new NpgsqlConnection(postgreConnectionString))
        {
            using (var reader = dbInstance.QueryMultiple(spName, new { std_id = Params[0].value }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
            {
                students = reader.Read<JSONData>().ToList();
            }
        }

        return students;
    }
```

**Implementation Method:**

```
public List<string> ExecuteProcedure(string spName, List<QueryParam> Params)
    {
        var list = objDLOperation.ExecutePostgres(spName, Params);
        var strList = new List<string>();

        list.ForEach(x => strList.Add(x.JSONResult));

        return strList;

    }
```

This `strList` is always a List of `null` values

**Entity Class:**

```
    public class JSONData
    {
      public string JSONResult { get; set; }
    }
```

**pl/pgSQL Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.usp_getstudent(std_id integer)
RETURNS SETOF json 
AS $function$

BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
select row_to_json(result) from (select * from student where id = std_id) as result;
END  

$function$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column appears to be either named `result`, or be anonymous - but your local type has a property called `JSONResult`. Dapper is fussy about names. If you make the names match, it should work fine. However, frankly:

- if you're only returning one column, there's no need for an entity - just use `<string>` (this also bypasses the naming issue - dapper doesn't care about names for single column fetches)
- if you're only returning one grid, there's no need for `QueryMultiple` - just use `Query<T>`

As a **very** minor point: `.AsList()` will be more efficient than `.ToList()` - avoids any additional copying.

Personally, I'd say "return typed columns, not JSON", but: that's up to you.

Comment: The result set is always (single column x single/multiple rows) in my case. So in that case naming should not be a factor ?

Comment: Naming is a factor. Dapper is getting "result" and tries to map it to "JSONResult" in the Entity Class. That fails.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation both Marc & Palle :)

Comment: @izengod naming is only ignored if the T is a simple well-known type, not a class etc; or when we deploy the value-tuples support, naming is ignored for value tuples